# SQL Server is allowing X lock on shared lock which is cause of deadlock

Tags: sql-server

This is a strange finding. I am doing select and delete on one session and delete on another session on the same row please see my code below. departmentid has clustered index.

```
------Session 1----------
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
select * from HumanResources.Department

------session 2 ------------
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
delete from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9

--session 1 -----------

delete from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9
```

This is what should happen.

- Session 1 gets shared locks on each row
- Now concurrently session 2 executes `delete` statement and should put a `[u]` lock on the row and then tries to convert the `u` lock to `X` lock which is blocked because of `s` lock been held by session 1
- Now session 1 executes `delete` statement tries to put `X` lock but is blocked by the `u` lock of session 2. Hence deadlock happens.

However when I see the deadlock graph I get a different picture. Deadlock graph tells that session 1 grants S lock. Session 2 grants X lock(I have confusion here) how can x lock be granted on S lock. See the deadlock graph below :

```
&lt;victimProcess id="process5d1a718"/&gt;
  &lt;process-list&gt;
   &lt;process id="process5d1a718" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594073907200 (15ac4ff5e281)" waittime="2723" ownerId="21790" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-03-06T15:44:12.863" XDES="0x6056c08" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="6016" status="suspended" spid="52" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-03-06T15:44:53.147" lastbatchcompleted="2016-03-06T15:44:12.863" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" hostname="SAMAR-PC" hostpid="3620" loginname="samar-PC\samar" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="21790" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200"&gt;
    &lt;executionStack&gt;
     &lt;frame procname="" line="1" stmtstart="24" sqlhandle="0x0200000033392c164aa2164aaf9c828974edf396604cba95"&gt;
     &lt;/frame&gt;
     &lt;frame procname="" line="1" sqlhandle="0x02000000e46e292caa2d578b8876190ff31f36bfdf42b892"&gt;
     &lt;/frame&gt;
    &lt;/executionStack&gt;
    &lt;inputbuf&gt;
delete from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9    &lt;/inputbuf&gt;
   &lt;/process&gt;
   &lt;process id="process19b1c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594074103808 (10aa4711661d)" waittime="21212" ownerId="21981" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-03-06T15:44:34.657" XDES="0x6b4c280" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="4148" status="suspended" spid="55" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-03-06T15:44:34.657" lastbatchcompleted="2016-03-06T15:43:36.970" lastattention="2016-03-06T15:33:58.423" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="SAMAR-PC" hostpid="3620" loginname="samar-PC\samar" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="21981" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200"&gt;
    &lt;executionStack&gt;
     &lt;frame procname="" line="3" stmtstart="24" sqlhandle="0x0200000033392c164aa2164aaf9c828974edf396604cba95"&gt;
     &lt;/frame&gt;
     &lt;frame procname="" line="3" stmtstart="136" sqlhandle="0x02000000c3907d12b9a0c511ab9b3c2966aa00fd5258d812"&gt;
     &lt;/frame&gt;
    &lt;/executionStack&gt;
    &lt;inputbuf&gt;
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
delete from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9    &lt;/inputbuf&gt;
   &lt;/process&gt;
  &lt;/process-list&gt;
  &lt;resource-list&gt;
   &lt;keylock hobtid="72057594073907200" dbid="7" objectname="" indexname="" id="locka1d5040" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594073907200"&gt;
    &lt;owner-list&gt;
     &lt;owner id="process19b1c8" mode="X"/&gt;
    &lt;/owner-list&gt;
    &lt;waiter-list&gt;
     &lt;waiter id="process5d1a718" mode="X" requestType="wait"/&gt;
    &lt;/waiter-list&gt;
   &lt;/keylock&gt;
   &lt;keylock hobtid="72057594074103808" dbid="7" objectname="" indexname="" id="locka1d4780" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594074103808"&gt;
    &lt;owner-list&gt;
     &lt;owner id="process5d1a718" mode="S"/&gt;
    &lt;/owner-list&gt;
    &lt;waiter-list&gt;
     &lt;waiter id="process19b1c8" mode="X" requestType="wait"/&gt;
    &lt;/waiter-list&gt;
   &lt;/keylock&gt;
  &lt;/resource-list&gt;
 &lt;/deadlock&gt;
&lt;/deadlock-list&gt;
</value>
      <text />
    </data>
  </event>
</RingBufferTarget>
```

I have another finding this is also very strange. If I change my select statement of session 1, that is I add where clause in it I do not get any deadlock. I only see session 2 been blocked and session 1 deletes the row with departmentid = 9. refer to my query below : -

```
------Session 1----------
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
select * from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9

------session 2 ------------
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
delete from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9

--session 1 -----------

delete from HumanResources.Department
where departmentid = 9
```

Can someone share some light here. All my concepts seem to be shattered here.

Comment: I just can't confirm this behavior - on my SQL Server 2014 instance, I can run the `SELECT` in session 1, but the `DELETE` in session 2 is blocked - as expected, since session 1 has a shared lock on that row in an open transaction, so that row cannot be deleted (since the session #2 cannot get an `X` lock on the row). BTW: a `DELETE` never gets a `U` lock first - that's **only** done by `UPDATE` statements, `DELETE` always get an `X` lock right away

Comment: then why am I getting deadlock? Session 2 is blocked and session 1 delete statement should work without any obstruction.

Comment: I don't know - as I said - I **cannot** reproduce this. What I get is a FK constraint violation error when trying to run the `DELETE` in session 1 - and session #2 will time out being blocked by session 1

Comment: I got the answer..The table has departmentid, name, groupname,modifieddate. Departmentid has clustered index and name  has nonclustered index and other columns - groupname and modifieddate        are included columns. So deadlocking is because of nonclustered index used by select statement in session 1

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I appreciate your valuable time and efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table has departmentid, name, groupname,modifieddate.

Departmentid has clustered index and name  has nonclustered index and other columns - groupname and modifieddate are included columns. This what happened.

1. select query in session 1 puts s lock on nonclustered index.
2. session 2 put x lock on departmentid = 9 on clustered index.
3. Now altering clustered index will update nonclustered index so session 2 tries to put X lock to nonclustered index but is blocked by S lock of session 1.
4. Session 1 tries to delete the same row by putting x lock which is blocked by X lock of session 2 on clustered index. Hence deadlock.

I resolved it by putting hint with (index = Clusteredindexname) with select statement in session 1 :

```
------Session 1----------
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
select * from HumanResources.Department with (index = Clusteredindexname)
```